# Boot Windows 10 iso from USB made on OSX

Tags: windows-10, boot, usb, bios, iso-image

I put together a PC using all new components.

I burnt an image of Windows 10 (iso downloaded from MS website) on my Mac OSX both using **terminal** and using **Etcher**, on disks formatted on **all possible formats and partition types**, onto **USB 3.0 and USB 2.0 flash drives**.

I enter the BIOS settings on the Asus Z170 Pro Gaming motherboard and:

- change the boot order so that USB is first
- try boot override options
- disable Fast Boot
- enable CMS (compatibility support)
- disable Secure Boot
- etc. etc.

The machine always goes back to the BIOS screen and never manages to boot from USB and show the Windows 10 installation screen.

What else can I be missing?

*EDIT: more info*

I am able to boot from other images on the USB drive like Debian and other images. This is specific to the Windows 10 iso image, downloaded from the Microsoft website.

Comment: Did you make the USB stick using Boot Camp Assistant? That's the only way for the Mac to make it bootable. http://www.windowscentral.com/how-create-windows-10-installer-usb-drive-mac has an easy instruction set.

Comment: Indeed it is an issue with the USB drive or the Windows 10 image on it as I managed to boot from Debian and OpenELEC images written **in the same way** and **on the same flash drives**. I tried with Boot Camp Assistant but it doesn't give me the options it gives everyone else, maybe because I'm missing the optical drive and it gives me a warning about that. I tried writing the image in many different ways, no luck. Next would be to try making it from Windows...

Answer (score 2):

I found it impossible to do this on a Mac (I have OSX El Capitan).

I **wrote the image to a USB from another Windows machine and it worked** fine.

This doesn't really answer the question so I can not accept it as an answe, but I'm putting here for people to see. Save yourselves some time and look for another Windows machine to do this, trying on a Mac might prove a waste of time, like in my case.